# Accessing FUT Web App from a Java application

Tags: java, httpclient

I am trying to access the [following URL](https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/#) using a Java application and I have some issues.

Accessing it via HttpClient (Java 12), but the body doesn't contain any link so I can follow them.

```java
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
     .uri(new URI("https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/#"))
     .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
     .GET()
     .build();

HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient.newBuilder()
    .proxy(ProxySelector.getDefault())
    .build()
    .send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

Does anyone know what framework I need to access to create an application that is able to log in and work with that web app?

Comment: Framework recommendations are off-topic for stack overflow

Comment: I want to know what is a framework capable of doing the job.

Comment: And such a request is off-topic. Sorry.

Comment: Understood. How should I proceed? Close the topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to access the site with success, using Selenium framework.